# SSRI and Antipsychotic Effect on Cognitive Functions

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

Does taking SSRI and antipsychotic result in cognitive dysfunctions?  What should happen to restore the Cognitive functions like problem solving skills, thinking, memory? What are the most effective ways either medication or program?